# for angular2/ng2, is there any way to clear model values when the field is hidden using ngIf

Tags: angular

for angular2/ng2, is there any way to clear model values when the field is hidden using ngIf

I was able do this in angularjs, but for angular2/ng2 can anyone give me some ideas. Much appreciated.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" novalidate>
<div>
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.Ethnicity" ngControl="Ethnicity" #Ethnicity="ngForm" required/>
</div>

<div *ngIf="contact.Ethnicity !=null">
<input resetHidden class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.FirstName" ngControl="FirstName" #FirstName="ngForm" required/>
</div>
</form>


import {Directive, ElementRef, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import {NgModel} from 'angular2/common';
@Directive({
  selector: '[resetHidden]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)' : 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class ResetHiddenDirective implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(public model:NgModel) {}
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue('');
    this.model.viewToModelUpdate('');
  }
  onInputChange(event){
    console.log('this.model.value before: '+this.model.value);
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(event.toUpperCase());
    console.log('this.model.value after: '+this.model.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code that demonstates the problem. What is a "model value" how do you use it?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, added some code, i was thinking of using a custom directive to handle this though failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage a control and its `updateValue` or set the bound element using `ngModel` to do that:

```
constructor() {
  this.ctrl = new Control('');
}

hideInput() {
  this.inputHidden = true;
  this.ctrl.updateValue('');
  this.someValue = '';
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="inputHidden">
  <input [ngFormControl]="ctrl" [(ngModel)]="someValue"/>
</div>
<div (click)="hideInput()">Hide</div>
```

Comment: for this is going to be a relative large form with a log re-renderings, is there a way to utilize a custom directive to save repeated work?